# Avoiding Chase monthly checking account fee

Tags: united-states, banking, fees, checking-account

With my checking account I have maintained a daily balance greater than 1500 dollars to avoid the 12 dollar monthly fee. As I earned more income I started moving it to a savings. Now I have accumulated enough money to use the other ways to avoid monthly fees. I'm not sure whether or not I fully understand the last one.

1. Direct deposit totaling $500 or more made to this account
2. OR a balance at the beginning of each day of $1,500 or more in this account
3. OR an average beginning day balance of $5,000 or more in any combination of this account and linked qualifying deposits/investments

Does the third one mean the total balance of the checking account and a linked account to the checking (**with the overdraft protection**), or just the total balance of all accounts (**checking, savings, etc.**)?

Comment: It's the total balance of money that you have in your Chase accounts.  I sure hope that you got their free $500  bonus for opening the MM and checking account.  BTW, did you know that 1/2 the people that you know are below average?  ;->)

Comment: Ok, thank you. And no, what do you mean by MM?

Comment: MM = Money Market

Comment: A linked account is one that the Chase website knows belongs to you and thus is visible on the same page (or in a different tab on the same page) as your checking account.

Comment: @BobBaerker Even if the answer is short, please post answers to questions as answers, not comments. [Here’s why.](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2299/10997)

Comment: Slightly Higher - In some banks, assets held in brokerage  accounts are also considered for meeting  savings and checking account minimums.  The safest thing to do is to check with Chase  because they offer a variety of packages and each may have different requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the third one mean the total balance of the checking account and a linked account to the checking, or just the total balance of all accounts?

Linked accounts.  Definitely **just linked accounts**.  (I'm also a Chase customer, and ran into this very problem a couple of months ago.)

Comment: This is only for accounts linked of a checking account by overdraft protection? Example linking a savings account for a checking fro overdraft protection.

Comment: I dubious whether ODP is what links them.